# Postgres list constraints that use a stored procedure

Tags: postgresql, functions, postgresql-9.6, check-constraints

I have a postgres database (v9.6) and I have multiple `CHECK` constraints that use user-defined functions.

something like:

```
CREATE TABLE payment (
  amount bigint,
  CONSTRAINT amount_gt_0 CHECK (round_amount(amount) > 0)
);
```

where `round_amount` is user-defined function.

Is it possible to get a list of all constraint or at least tables that use such constraints?

*postgresql version is 9.6*

Answer (score 1):

It looks like that there is already a view called [information_schema.check_constraint_routine_usage](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/infoschema-check-constraint-routine-usage.html) that provide this information.

The view originally only shows routines owned by the current role but you can find the original query by typing `\d+ information_schema.check_constraint_routine_usage` and tweak it.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean this?

```
SELECT
   cls.relname, 
   const.conname,
   const.consrc
FROM 
   pg_catalog.pg_constraint const
   INNER JOIN pg_catalog.pg_class cls ON cls.oid = const.conrelid
   INNER JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace ns ON ns.oid = const.connamespace
WHERE 
   ns.nspname = '<your_schema>'
   AND const.contype = 'c'
   AND const.consrc like '%round_amount%'
```

Comment: That query assumes that I already know the function name `round_amount` but in my case I don't.

I'm trying to find every constraint that relies on user-defined function.